# What happens to AWS Lambda code, under the hood, when we add serializer?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

What happens with .netcore Lambda programm when we add the following serializer attribute (LambdaSerializer) in the beginning of Lambda.cs file?

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]   

namespace SimpleScheduling.Lambda;

public class Function
{
    var runnerName = "Jim Wilson";
    public void FunctionHandler(EventInfo input,
        ILambdaContext context)
    {
        switch (input.ActionName)
        {
            case "PatreonMail":
                context.Logger.LogInformation($"Received call for {input.ActionName}");
                break;
            case "VipPatreonMail":
                context.Logger.LogInformation($"Received call for {input.ActionName}");
                break;
            default:
                context.Logger.LogInformation($"Unknown action");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, it is clear what happens at the top level - JSON input will be converted into .net class. However, I wanted to understand what changes happens with the program execution when this attribute is added? Any specific aws assembly/classes injected as dependency to all classes where input happens? Perhaps, my question is specfic to AWS Lambda, but it is more common question for the other .net core projects.

Answer (score 1):

In this case your question is AWS Lambda specific. The .NET Lambda runtime client that loads your code up looks for this attribute on either the assembly or method and then creates an instance of the type specified in the attribute and then uses that for serialization.

The .NET Lambda runtime client is open source and you can find the code that looks up the attribute here. https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/51a367b314d539d2fa591b299d7836cb18987c45/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeLoader.cs#L193

**Updated with more details**

At the Lambda service level events coming in the function and the responses coming out are a JSON document. To allow .NET developers to work with .NET types the .NET Lambda runtime client looks for a registered serializer using the LambdaSerializer. It then instantiates the type using the default constructor and casts to Amazon.Lambda.Core.ILambdaSerializer. The .NET Lambda runtime client then uses the ILambdaSerializer to convert from the Lambda native JSON to the .NET POCOs. The serializer registered by the LambdaSerializer attribute is for the Lambda runtime client to use.

Comment: I wanted to understand this bit better: <creates an instance of the type specified in the attribute and then uses that for serialization.>. 
1) Does it create a Serilizer object of the type: Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer? 
2) How does it work internally? Is an input being passed to this object being before passing it to Lambda Handler, or what is actually happening?